# How can I set up a password activity as with only numbers?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
public class Password extends Activity{

    Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, exit, okay;
    EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pass);



        one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
        zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
        okay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);

    }

        public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.button:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button2:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button3:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button4:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button5:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button6:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button7:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button8:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button9:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button10:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button11:text.setText("1");
                break;
            case R.id.button12:text.setText("1");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have made the pic attached below. I want to create this activity. I read something about sharedPreferences but it is still confusing me. Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

EDIT: Thanks a lot guys. I did some other thing. The switch case wasnt working so I added the code like 
one.setOnClickListener(){.....}
to each button. It is working now. 
Huge thanks to all of you. Never would have got ideas if I didnt post here.

Comment: Please clarify your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update**
try this

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:text.setText(text.getText()+"1");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:text.setText(text.getText()+"2");
            break;
        case R.id.button3:text.setText(text.getText()+"3");
            break;
        case R.id.button4:text.setText(text.getText()+"4");
            break;
        case R.id.button5:text.setText(text.getText()+"5");
            break;
        case R.id.button6:text.setText(text.getText()+"6");
            break;
        case R.id.button7:text.setText(text.getText()+"7");
            break;
        case R.id.button8:text.setText(text.getText()+"8");
            break;
        case R.id.button9:text.setText(text.getText()+"9");
            break;
        case R.id.button10:text.setText("1");
            break;
        case R.id.button11:text.setText("1");
            break;
        case R.id.button12:text.setText("1");
            break;
    }
```

and for other buttons place appropriate functions

for edittext

```
 android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
   android:inputType="numberPassword"
```

in your `edittext` in xml file 
and for `SharedPreferences` refer to Waza_Be's answer

Comment: Wouldnt that make the input as number only? I want the user to use the numbers I have given on screen like applock or dropbox does.

Comment: you can try creating your own xml layout with buttons and a edittext then

Comment: What you are referring, is it the same as I have posted the pic above?

Comment: yes create a layout similar to the picture above .... use buttons and after user presses "ok" button validate it with the one in the SharedPreferences..

Comment: m not sure if it's a good idea but you can create this sort of layout like in a calculator.. check here http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_BasicsUI.html

Comment: Actually I have done all that. What I currently dont know is how to set it up so that the value from those button will be entered in the field. I am unable to achieve that. Could you help for that?

Comment: Thanks but it isnt working. Nothing gets typed in the text area. I am using editText for that area if thats helpful.

Comment: as I have told in the question I have updated the code. Thanks a lot. Actually switch isnt working yet. Should I post the updated code? It works fine. Just I will have to make four of those things and then do some string concatenation to provide password.

Comment: good that ur problem is solved.. but if u put this onclick method in each buttons xml i.e. `android:onClick="onClick"` then your switch code might work.

Answer (score 2):

try this may be help you
use this in your xml file

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ems="10"
android:inputType="numberPassword" >

<requestFocus />
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the password, you could do something like: (**This in not really secure, not aimed for banking app ;-)**)

```
    SharedPreferences settings= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor=settings.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("password","123456");
    // if 4 digits: prefEditor.putInt("password",1234);
    prefEditor.commit();
```

Working with numbers is a little bit tricky because of the maximum value of integers:

> Java int:int is 32 bit signed type ranges from –2,147,483,648 to
>   2,147,483,647.

Of course, if you force a 4 digit PIN for password, no problems to work with int, but as you will work with String in TextView/EditText, turning it to numbers sounds not the best idea

and when the user want to login to the Activity, just compare what he typed with:

```
settings.getInt("password",-1)
```

Comment: Yes I intend to work with 4 digit password only. If you see the dropbox app it has the password option. I want to set up something similar so some activity in my app will be accessible through password only.

Comment: So, my answer sounds like to fill all requests, isn't it?

Comment: I am actually new to this. So where can I understand all this code? I have added the code you gave me but still nothing is happening. I am unable to get it to work so that user would press the buttons on the screen and that would appear in the field.

Comment: You asked about preferences, I answered about preferences, and the answer was about how to react on click event! Awesome!

Comment: Sorry I read that preferences is needed to do that and make a password activity so I asked that.